# Delete POLINE based on the line which is marked to delete using automation script

Tags: python, maximo

I would like to know whether its possible to delete a poline using automation script when some other poline is marked for deletion ( DELETE icon) is selected. For example I have a PO which has 3 lines and when the first line is marked for deletion then the second line in the PO should also get deleted. Both the lines have a value in common. I tried the below script however there is no error but its not working. The script is called during po.status attribute launch point.

```
if mbo.getMboValue("STATUS").isModified() and mbo.getString("STATUS") =='APPR' :
po = mbo.getMboSet("POLINE")
polineSet = po.count()
if (polineSet > 0): 
    for i in range(0,polineSet):
        poline = po.getMbo(i)
        if (poline.toBeDeleted()==True):
            polineSet1 = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("POLINE",mbo.getUserInfo())
            polineSet1.setWhere("ponum = '" + poline.getString("ponum") + "' and remark = '" + poline.getString("remark") + "' and revisionnum = '" + poline.getInt("revisionnum") + "' and siteid = '" + poline.getString("siteid") + "'")
            polineSet1.count()
            polineSet1.delete()
```

Updated : Invoke script on Object Delete.

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
poLineSet = mbo.getMboSet("CXPOLINE")
if poLineSet.count() > 0:
 poLine = poLineSet.getMbo(0)
 poLine.delete(MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your script is running? It seems an odd situation where a record is flagged to be deleted, not saved yet (which would actually delete it) *and yet is still having its status changed*.

The primary problem here is that you are getting the second PO that is to be deleted in a new/separate transaction (and from the database, not from the in-memory data, if that matters) and not saving that transaction. Your first PO that is being deleted is tied to some process that probably naturally ends in a save call, so that's why you don't have to worry about explicitly calling it on the data in the set that triggers your script. However, that natural "save" call there will only save the records on that transaction. When you get a Set from MXServer like that, you are creating a new transaction and putting its data (and any other related data you fetch from it) in that new transaction. When you are done with that, Maximo does not know if you want to keep your changes or not (or for that matter, it doesn't even know when you are actually done with it), so it won't save it on its own. You need to explicitly call "save()" on one of the MBO sets in that transaction (and only one of the sets in that transaction) to get Maximo to persist the changes to the database.

Be careful in your case though. Your data is tightly coupled and therefore has a decent chance of already being in the main set that triggered your script. If the data was changed there already, then your change will have the same record modified in two different transactions, which will cause Maximo to throw the dreaded "refetch" error ("Your record has been updated by another user. Please refetch the record and try again.").

Comment: well the script is getting called however poline.toBeDeleted() returns false. Is there a way to fetch the record that is marked for deletion using script ?

Comment: Well, I guess that was part of my thinking when asking if the script was being called. Since all of the checks are in the script, it will certainly be getting called, but your conditions may be failing because of the very narrow case you are going for. I'm not sure how this status is being changed, but if done through the typical UI, a save call is made when the change status dialog is brought up. That should persist any pending deletion changes, meaning it should actually cause the first POLine record to be deleted. Make sure the POLine in question is really still in the set.

Comment: I have tried to invoke the script during object deletion rather than update and its getting invoked however I am not sure how to invoke delete(long accessModifier) method in automation script as this is the method used in POLine.class

Comment: I don't think you really need to call the version with the access modifier; I believe the normal, no parameters version would work just as well. Aside from that, your script looks good. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: if i simply give delete() it doesnt work and gives error as method not found. If i give delete(2L) or delete (11L) then class cast exception comes up. Im not sure how to invoke the delete method here.

Comment: It seems odd you would get that, but what is the full class cast exception? That could be quite revealing to see what the script thinks you have at this point, and might explain why the delete call doesn't work.

Comment: the error is as follows... BMXAA7837E- An error occured that prevented the script from running. java.lang.classcastException.java.lang.classcastException:psdi.app.po.POLine incompatible with psdi.app.po.PORemote in <script>at line number5. Hope this helps..thanks!

Comment: PORemote? You shouldn't have a *Remote* in most normal situations. Is this script being triggered from some kind of RMI integration, like maybe a mobile solution? On top of that, it thinks you have a PO (I might be reading this backwards) and is trying to cast it to POLine. Based on the script you show in your question, it shouldn't try to do that and even still there is nothing in there that is not already on MBO in the first place (so both objects would have it). And the "delete()" method not being found is odd in this context because it would exist on both of those objects too.